# How do i access the bar chart value from data.count in my recharts Bar label prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, recharts

I need to access the value of each individual rechart Bar inside of the component to create a custom label which appends a custom text string after the value. I have found examples online but it looks like the previous way of accessing the individual value for each bar doesn't work in the newest version of recharts.

I tried accessing the it with the index value from the map function but s.series is just one array so I'm unsure of the the data is being rendered individually for each bar.

```
const ThickBarChart: React.FC<{
  CustomTooltip?: React.ReactNode;
  barVariant?: 'narrow' | 'wide';
  data?: {
    count: number;
    name: string;
  }[];
  upperBound?: number;
  title?: React.ReactNode;
  chartHeight?: number;
  series: Array<{
    key: string;
    name: string;
    fill: colors;
  }>;
  aspectRatio?: number;
  domain?: [number, number];
  ticks?: Array<number>;
  includeBarOutline?: boolean;
  loading?: boolean;
  roundedCorners?: boolean;
  average?: number;
  barColor: string;
  appendValueText?: string;
}> = ({
  data,
  upperBound,
  chartHeight,
  series,
  aspectRatio,
  domain,
  ticks,
  includeBarOutline,
  loading,
  roundedCorners,
  average,
  barColor,
  appendValueText,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ chartHeight, roundedCorners });
  const labelFormatter = ({ value }: { value: number }) => (
    <text className={classes.styledText}>
      `${value} ${appendValueText || ''}`
    </text>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.barGraphWrapper}>
      <div className={classes.relWrapper}>
        <div className={cn({ [classes.absWrapper]: chartHeight })}>
          <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={chartHeight} aspect={aspectRatio} debounce={1}>
            {loading ? (
              <div className={classes.loadingWrapper}>
                <CircularProgress size={100} color="secondary" />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <RechartBar
                data={data}
                margin={{
                  bottom: 30,
                  left: 24,
                  right: 24,
                  top: 30,
                }}
                style={{
                  ...(includeBarOutline && {
                    stroke: colors.navy,
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                  }),
                }}
              >
                <CartesianGrid vertical={false} stroke={colors.grayFour} margin={{ left: 10 }} />
                {upperBound !== 0 && (
                  <XAxis dataKey="name" axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={16} />
                )}
                <YAxis
                  ticks={ticks}
                  tickCount={5}
                  axisLine={false}
                  tickLine={false}
                  domain={domain}
                  tickMargin={16}
                  tickFormatter={shortenNumber}
                />
                {upperBound !== 0 &&
                  series.map((s) => (
                    <Bar
                      style={{ stroke: 'none', strokeDasharray: '5 5' }}
                      name={s.key}
                      key={s.key}
                      stackId="x"
                      dataKey={s.key}
                      fill={barColor}
                      radius={[4, 4, 4, 4]}
                      barSize={124}
                      label={
                        <text className={classes.styledText}>{`${
                          s.key /* HOW DO I GET VALUE HERE? */
                        }  ${appendValueText}`}</text>
                      }
                      isAnimationActive={false}
                    />
                  ))}
                {average && (
                  <ReferenceLine
                    y={average}
                    stroke={colors.purple}
                    strokeDasharray="7 7"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                  />
                )}
              </RechartBar>
            )}
          </ResponsiveContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```